# How to map an array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I'm quite confused as to how I'm supposed to loop through my array of objects. I was using `.map` however, I've been informed that this should only be used for arrays and I actually have an object. I've followed the Reacjs documentation for this solution so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

```
this.state.data: (3) [Object, Object, Object]
[{
company: Company A,
title: Title A,
uniqueId: uniqueId A
},
{
company: Company A,
title: Title A,
uniqueId: uniqueId A
}]
```

Path: `function`

```
function PositionList(props) {
  const positions = props.positions;

  const listPositions = positions.map((position) =>
    // Correct! Key should be specified inside the array.
    <PositionItem key={position.uniqueId.toString()}
              company={position.company}
              uniqueId={position.uniqueId}
              onChange={props.onChange}
    />
  );

  return (
    <ul>
      {listPositions}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Map is fine with arrays of objects. You can't use map to iterate a single (not in an array) object, because Object doesn't support the map method.

Comment: Sorry does that mean my code is correct?

Comment: It looks like it. Does it run and do what you want?

Comment: Your code looks fine, Do you get errors with this?

Comment: I get errors after the code has loaded and I run `handleInputChange`. With each key stroke it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`.

Comment: It's an array of objects, which still is an Array and doing `map` on arrays is just fine. So, I think you can edit the title to make better sense, as here you're not mapping an object.

Comment: @bp123 that error means that `position.uniqueId` is undefined. Can you `console.log` position in the map function and tell us what you got?

Comment: Ok. The error was related to me using append `...this.state.data` in `handleInputChange` which I don't think is required. Now I need to figure out how do `handleSubmit` for a form which is populated with an array of objects. I think that is another quiestion